# How do I output only CERTAIN submission values in webform HTML mail?

Tags: webforms, bookings

So here is my problem: In HTML email template, I don't want the user who chose "hotel" to receive the same output values than a user who chose a flight.

I created a booking webform with 30 components with 3 conditional choices (if user chooses hotel, the form looks different than for a user who chooses flight)

My HTML email template looks like this:

```
  <p>Goal of reservation: [submission:values:goal_of_reservation:nolabel]</p>
  <p>Name: [site:current-user:field-name]</p>
```

etc

The Result looks like this:

[image]

With my setup, all users receive the same HTML template and I want to avoid that. **I want them to receive only the outputs and labels based on their choice of submission.**

I thought about adding a if-statement to my HTML template which based on the users choice, the HTML doesn't send certain values. Anyone got a better idea?
Yes webform has an option "Exclude empty values", but that's not exactly what solves my problem.

I don't understand why webform doesn't allow this feature from scratch.

Comment: How about using "Webform Rules", so that you can trigger some Rules logic with appropriate Rules Conditiions, and based on these conditions then send an HTML eMail?